# Getting all nodes that have a specific term id using EntityFieldQuery

Tags: 7, database

I have been using the following line to get all the nodes with a term id

```
taxonomy_select_nodes($tid);
```

But now I want to sort the output by weight (field_audio_weight - field I created).
How can I achieve the same output using `EntityFieldQuery` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery()
  ->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->fieldCondition('field_taxonomy_reference', 'tid', TERM_ID)
  ->fieldOrderBy('field_audio_weight', 'value', 'DESC');

$results = $query->execute();
```

Check these articles for more information:

https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/entityfieldquery-let-drupal-do-the-heavy-lifting-pt-1/

https://www.phase2technology.com/blog/entityfieldquery-let-drupal-do-the-heavy-lifting-pt-2/

Comment: ->fieldOrderBy('field_audio_weight', 'DESC'); should be: ->fieldOrderBy('field_audio_weight', 'value', 'DESC');

Comment: Ok, edited. I wrote it off the cuff, which is why I linked to the two articles on how to use it and how to extend on it if needed.